How can apply two MudBlazor Masks in a input?
<MudItem xs="12" lg="8" Class="mb-0 pt-0 d-flex flex-row items-center" Justify="Justify.FlexStart">
    <MudItem xs="2" Class="mb-0 d-flex flex-row" Style="align-items:center" Justify="Justify.Center">@L["Series"]</MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="6">
        <MudTextField Class="series-key-input" Style="border-radius:10px; text-transform: uppercase;" Mask="@validationForSeries" AutoFocus=false @bind-Value=Model.Series Label="@L["Series"]" Margin="Margin.Dense" Variant="Variant.Outlined" For="@(() => Model.Series)" Required="true" />
    </MudItem>
</MudItem>

How can I put 2 Masks here?
public IMask validationForSeries = new BlockMask(new Block('a', 1, 3), new Block('0', 1, 7));

public IMask validationForSeries = new RegexMask("^\[A-Za-z0-9\]{0,10}$");

I am going to use two MudBlazor Masks in a input.
